# insert a statement before the execution of a loop

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

In LLVM intermediate representation, how can I insert an instruction for a loop, which will be executed exactly once before the execution of that loop? Inserting the instruction to the preheader does not work, because preheader is NULL for some loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the loop does not have a preheader, you can create new preheader.

Here is an example http://www.cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring08/cs259/llvm-2.2/lib/Transforms/Utils/LoopSimplify.cpp or http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-23/clang/lib/Transforms/Utils/LoopSimplify.cpp (find function `InsertPreheaderForLoop` and call to it)

```cpp
/// InsertPreheaderForLoop - Once we discover that a loop doesn't have a
/// preheader, this method is called to insert one.  This method has two phases:
/// preheader insertion and analysis updating.
///
void LoopSimplify::InsertPreheaderForLoop(Loop *L) {
  BasicBlock *Header = L->getHeader();

  // Compute the set of predecessors of the loop that are not in the loop.
  std::vector<BasicBlock*> OutsideBlocks;
  for (pred_iterator PI = pred_begin(Header), PE = pred_end(Header);
       PI != PE; ++PI)
    if (!L->contains(*PI))           // Coming in from outside the loop?
      OutsideBlocks.push_back(*PI);  // Keep track of it...

  // Split out the loop pre-header.
  BasicBlock *NewBB =
    SplitBlockPredecessors(Header, ".preheader", OutsideBlocks);


  //===--------------------------------------------------------------------===//
  //  Update analysis results now that we have performed the transformation
  //

  // We know that we have loop information to update... update it now.
  if (Loop *Parent = L->getParentLoop())
    Parent->addBasicBlockToLoop(NewBB, LI->getBase());

  DT->splitBlock(NewBB);
  if (DominanceFrontier *DF = getAnalysisToUpdate<DominanceFrontier>())
    DF->splitBlock(NewBB);

  // Make sure that NewBB is put someplace intelligent, which doesn't mess up
  // code layout too horribly.
  PlaceSplitBlockCarefully(NewBB, OutsideBlocks, L);
}
```